# How to get depth of WebView in Android?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to get depth of `WebView's` object in `Android`. But I can't find so I develop using `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished`.

```
boolean mIsInProgress = false;
int depth = 0;
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        if(!mIsInProgress) {
            depth++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if(mIsInProgress) {
            mIsInProgress = false;
        }
    }
});
```

And this is method of decrease depth when click hardware back key.

```
private void moveBack(){
    if(!mIsInProgress) {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            depth--;
        } else if (mActivity != null) {
            mActivity.finish();
        }

        mIsInProgress= true;
    }
}
```

At First, I think it's really work nice. But `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` has timing issue.

> 1. WebView has 1 depth.
> 2. Move page through click any link.
> 3. Move back --> Calling `onPageStarted`.
> 4. Move page through click any link, before calling `onPageFinished`. --> Calling `onPageStarted`.
> 5. Calling `onPageFinished`.

It wasn't called `onPageFinished` in between 3 step and 4 step, so can't increase depth in 4 step. (But I need `mIsInProgress` variable cause `onPageStarted` sometimes called twice.)

How can I get depth of WebView exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebViewBackForwardList` returned by `WebView.copyBackForwardList()` [(doc)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#copyBackForwardList()). In the back-forward list, `getCurrentIndex()` return the current position in the history list, and the size of the list is the overall history depth.